# based word for battling and lemmatization

Tags: python-3.x, nltk, wordnet, lexical-analysis, lemmatization

All,

What is the base form of **battling**? Lemmatization results in **battling** where as I think it should be **battle**. Is my understanding of lemmatization wrong?

```
from nltk import download
download('wordnet')
from nltk.stem.wordnet import WordNetLemmatizer

lemmatizer = WordNetLemmatizer()

def get_lemma(word):
    return lemmatizer.lemmatize(word)

get_lemma('battling')
```

The same is for the word **coming**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default lemmatization `pos` (Part Of Speech) is noun for the `lemmatize` method. And it produces the output `battling`.

If you change the `pos` to a verb, as is the case here, you get the proper result.

```
lemmatizer.lemmatize("battling", wordnet.VERB)
```

will give the base `battle`